# Move current line to the header of current buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to find a way to automate/simplify the following use case:

I'm somewhere in the middle of a long file and I paste something.

Then I would like to send/move the current line (to the top header of the currently opened file). Most often this is some import/require function.

All of these ideally should happen without losing the relative position in a file (without setting markers manually).

How can I do this?

---

If it is important, I use Emacs primarily in evil-mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```lisp
(defun move-region-to-beginning-of-buffer (beg end)
  "Move the region to the beginning of the buffer, then go back."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((text (buffer-substring beg end)))
    (save-excursion
      (delete-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (insert text))))
```

Use it by selecting the text (actually, right after paste it is already marked) to be sent to the beginning of the buffer, then <kbd>M-x move-region-to-beginning-of-buffer RET</kbd>.
You can also bind this command to a key the usual way.

Comment: Region selection approach might be even better. Thank you!

Comment: @NikitaFedyashev: wdym?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was an explicit region selection rather than just the current line